# Filling nsmutablearray objective-c

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray, nspredicate

can somebody please explain me the difference between the following code snippets for filling the myStrings array:

```
    NSString *match = @"ad*.png";

    NSString *bundleRoot = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
    NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSArray *dirContents = [fm contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:bundleRoot error:nil];
    NSPredicate *fltr = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF like %@", match];

    NSArray *onlyPNGs = [dirContents filteredArrayUsingPredicate:fltr];

    myStrings = [NSMutableArray array];
    for(int i=0;i<[onlyPNGs count];i++)
    {
        [myStrings addObject:(NSString *)[onlyPNGs objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
    NSLog([myStrings description]);
```

When I fill my array this way, after the constructor, myStrings becomes null somehow but instead of filling with filter, if I add items manually everythings fine:

```
     [myStrings addObject:@"adburgerking1.png"];
    [myStrings addObject:@"adburgerking2.png"];
    [myStrings addObject:@"adburgerking3.png"];
    [myStrings addObject:@"addominos1.png"];
    [myStrings addObject:@"admcdonalds1.png"];
    [myStrings addObject:@"admcdonalds2.png"];
    [myStrings addObject:@"admcdonalds3.png"];
    [myStrings addObject:@"admeshuriskender1.png"];
    [myStrings addObject:@"adquickchina1.png"];
    [myStrings addObject:@"adsencam1.png"];
    [myStrings addObject:@"adsultanahmetkoftecisi1.png"];
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Out of curiosity, what kind of variable is 'myStrings'? Is it just a regular ivar, or is it a property? And if it's a property, are you using ARC? If you're using ARC, make sure that the property type is either STRONG or COPY, otherwise it'll get released and nil'ed out.

Comment: Im quite new to iOS programming but im trying to store the file names as a NSString*. In the header file:
@property(nonatomic, retain)NSMutableArray * myStrings;

Comment: Could you perhaps have a local variable also called `myStrings` that's hiding the instance variable?

Comment: I do not have any local variable. myStrings is defined in the header file and I initialize it in the init function. But I found the problem and I corrected it:) However I still do not get the difference between those to code snippets:/ One works the other does not:)
//myStrings = [[NSMutableArray array]];
myStrings = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your first comment: `myStrings` is a property with `retain` semantics - a property will only retain a value if accessed as a property (`self.myStrings = ...`), if you directly assign to a underlying variable (`myStrings = ...`) there will be no retain.

From your second comment: `[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]` vs. `[NSMutableArray array]` - `[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]` returns an array you own, you don't `retain` it to keep it; however `[NSMutableArray array]` returns an array you do not own, you must `retain` it if you wish to keep it.

So what you need is:

```
self.myStrings = [NSMutableArray array];
```

The RHS returns an array you do not own, the LHS will `retain` it - now it will stay around.

You might be tempted to use:

myStrings = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

as the RHS returns an array you own and the LHS just stores it *without* retaining it as you're accessing the variable and not the property. However this version will not `release` any previous array referenced by `myStrings` so does not work in general.

The rule is always access a property using dot notation, with the possible exception of a classes `init` and `dealloc` methods (this last bit is debated).